# Fixing wild card capture error for reduce() operation with Java-Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, wildcard, reduce

I want to create a generic method to calculate summation of values in the given `List`.

Instead of writing code below:

```
final BigDecimal spend = forecasts.stream()
      .filter(forecast -> Objects.nonNull(forecast.getPrice()))
      .map(PartForecastSupplierDto::getPrice)
      .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

I want to write code like this:

```
public <T, R> R sum(Collection<T> collection, 
                    Predicate<? super T> predicate,
                    Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper,
                    R identity, final BinaryOperator<R> accumulator) {
    
    return CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(collection)
        .stream()
        .filter(predicate)
        .map(mapper)
        .reduce(identity, accumulator);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error like this:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `.<R>map(mapper)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a chain of method invocations, the type inference will not use information of a later invocation for the preceding invocation’s target type.

Therefore, the `.map(mapper)` produces a `Stream<? extends R>` regardless of the type inferred for the subsequent `reduce` operation.

The simplest way to fix this, is to provide an explicit type for the `map` step, i.e.

```java
public <T, R> R sum(Collection<T> collection, 
                    Predicate<? super T> predicate,
                    Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper,
                    R identity, final BinaryOperator<R> accumulator) {
    
    return collection
        .stream()
        .filter(predicate)
        .<R>map(mapper)
        .reduce(identity, accumulator);
}
```

Note that I have strong objections against the policy indicated by the method name `emptyIfNull`. A collection should not become `null` and you should reject `null` for collections as early as possible, to eliminate the cases. Silently doing something useful with `null` means protracting the problem and requiring more and more of those conditionals all over the place, instead of fixing the one source of `null`.

Note further that your method is not summing anymore, but performing an arbitrary Reduction, so the name doesn’t fit. Also, your specific use case is testing the property it will map to, so it would be simpler the swap the order of the steps

```java
final BigDecimal spend = forecasts.stream()
      .map(PartForecastSupplierDto::getPrice)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

which raises questions about the usefulness of a utility method that has a fixed constellation of `filter`, `map`, and `reduce` steps.

Comment: That's the correct exhaustive answer. I've overlooked the possibility of providing explicit type while applying the mapper function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises because the type of stream elements and the type of *identity* doesn't match. With the version of [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) operation you're using in your code, they should be identical:

> `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`

Where `T` is the type of stream element. In your case in the stream you have `? extends R`, but identity is of type `R`.

You need another flavor of [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) to solve the problem:

> ```
> <U> U reduce(U identity,
>              BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
>              BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
> ```

In such cases like accumulation `BigDecimal` values, you can use the same function for *accumulator* and *combiner*. And note that both functions need to be [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity).

Comment: The stream elements and the identity are both supposed to be `R` here. The error is just a small type inference issue.